# Migrating a Replicated Database from one SQLServer 2012 instance to another

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, migration, transactional-replication

We are working on a migration plan from old hardware to new hardware, these are SQL 2012 servers.
A couple of the databases heavily use transaction replication so I'm trying to avoid recreating and re-initializing them if possible.

Can I just restore the database on the new hardware with "Keep_Replication" and everything will be good or would restoring other databases such as MSDB/Master be required as well?

I'm not sure where all the metadata for replication is contained.

Also, any additional steps besides "Keep_CDC" to keep CDC tables active on the new hardware?

Comment: We do this where I work but it is not officially supported.  We restore master, msdb, distribution, and the publication database with the keep_replication switch but the new machine and server name needs to be the same exact name as the old machine and server. I would test this thoroughly before attempting it in production, and if something goes wrong in production, be prepared to start over from scratch.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams That's what I was afraid of, I don't want to mess with restoring Master on MSDB on a new server so I'll just script them out and recreate them all again.  Thank you!